# Play sound with wxhaskell not working on OSX?

Tags: wxhaskell

```
import Graphics.UI.WX

main :: IO ()
main = start $ do
   f <- frame []
   p <- panel f []

   set f [layout := minsize(Size 100 100) $ widget p]

   play (sound "alarm.wav")
```

This does not play a sound as I had hoped. This advice from around 2006 is all I could find: "Did you build wxWidgets with configuring --enable-sound
build option?" Is this still valid? If so, how do I do that?

Using OSX 10.9.5, GHC 7.10.2, WX 0.92.2.0